# tokenising a list of strings

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to tokenise a list of strings to be a list of words.
For example:

```
a=['NEWS FLASH: popcorn-flavored Tic-Tacs', 'The way']
```

I would like the output to be:

```
a=['NEWS', 'FLASH:', 'popcorn-flavored', 'Tic-Tacs', 'The', 'way']
```

I tried this code

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
tokenized = [word_tokenize(i) for i in a]
```

but it returns a single list for each sentence

```
[['NEWS', 'FLASH', ':', 'popcorn-flavored', 'Tic-Tacs'], ['The', 'way']]
```

Comment: Then flatten the lists (that might not be the best solution, but its a workaround).

Comment: `tokenized = word_tokenize(' '.join(a))`